# Is $E_{\operatorname{Tor}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ Zariski-closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a number field of finite degree over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with coefficients in $K$. Then $E_{\operatorname{Tor}}(L)$ is finite for every algebraic extension $L/K$ of finite degree, hence Zariski-closed.

Is $E_{\operatorname{Tor}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ Zariski-closed as well?

Comment: It's infinite proper subset, so no, since $E$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: @Wojowu that looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ is an algebraic curve, so it has Krull dimension 1. This means that any Zariski closed subset of $E(K)$ (for any field $K$) is either finite or all of $E(K)$. Now, if we let $K=\overline{\mathbb Q}$ and consider the subset of torsion points, then on one hand this subset is infinite (e.g. because it contains points of arbitrary order), but is not equal to all of $E(K)$ - that every elliptic curve over a number field has an algebraic point of infinite point is true, but somewhat tricky, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1577405/127263) for some references.

Comment: In fact the set of torsion points of an abelian variety over an algebraically closed field is always Zariski dense.